# Trying to set the color of lights via geometry nodes instancing

Tags: geometry-nodes, lighting, color, instances

I'm using Geometry Nodes in Blender 4.0.2 to instance a collection on points:
[image: Geometry node setup]

The collection contains a single light and a single mesh with a few materials. I'm trying to control the color of the light via an input parameter to the Geometry node group ("Color").

I am able to set the color onto a mesh material easily enough:
[image: Material node setup]

But when I play the same trick with the light color:
[image: Light node setup]

The light's actual emission color is black. Is this just a bug, or is there a way I can get my parameter to the GeoNode setup to control the color of the lights I've instanced? Note that I don't want to use an emissive material as it doesn't illuminate the scene the same way a light does (using Cycles).

Comment: Doesn't work in Eevee, in Cycles you can control the color of a normal mesh emission. You can also have multiple lights with various colors in a collection and pick the light, but obviously it's going to have a terrible performance if you have 1 light object for each possible color (would require 16777216 objects) and by terrible performance I mean, I don't know anyone to succesfully use that many objects :D

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, I'm using Cycles. And I also mentioned I can successfully apply the attribute to mesh materials. What I want to be able to do is apply the attribute to a light. The direct approach doesn't work. I was wondering if anyone knew of some back-handed trick I could use to accomplish my goal - to apply instance attributes to an instanced light (color and intensity).

Comment: To my knowledge you can't set light color in geonodes. In Cycles use an emissive surface, where you can easily set the color using an attribute.